# Callback on each QML Video frame

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML QuickControls 2 application with a `Video` component/control. I want to create a C++ callback to handle each frame in the video. The C++ callback function will process each frame, ie, find the edges in the image/frame and return that edge image for the UI to display.

How can I hook all this up? Ie, somehow tell the QML to call a c++ callback on each frame?

```
Video {
    id: video
    fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectFit
    anchors.fill : parent
    source: "file:///D:/cards.mp4"
    muted: true

    focus: true
    Keys.onSpacePressed: video.playbackState == MediaPlayer.PlayingState ? video.pause() : video.play()
    Keys.onLeftPressed: video.seek(video.position - 5000)
    Keys.onRightPressed: video.seek(video.position + 5000)
}
```

My callback class, not sure if correct:

```
class ImageProcessor : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ImageProcessor(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE void processImage(QString va);

signals:

public slots:
};
```

Comment: "_call a c++ callback on each frame_" Hi can you clarify this? How are you passing the frame into the callback function? Also, what is the parameter `QString va` supposed to represent?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `VideoOutput` from the video:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    color: "black"

    MediaPlayer {
        id: player
        source: "file://video.webm"
        autoPlay: true
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: videoOutput
        source: player
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

You can add filters to the `VideoOutput`. For example here a `faceRecognitionFilter`:

```
VideoOutput {
    ...
    filters: [ faceRecognitionFilter ]
}
```

In the `C++` implemtation of the filter you can reach the frame:

```
QVideoFrame FaceRecogFilterRunnable::run(QVideoFrame *input, const QVideoSurfaceFormat &surfaceFormat, RunFlags flags)
{
    // Convert the input into a suitable OpenCV image format, then run e.g. cv::CascadeClassifier,
    // and finally store the list of rectangles into a QObject exposing a 'rects' property.
    ...
    return *input;
}
```

You can collect some info here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html
http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/03/20/introducing-video-filters-in-qt-multimedia/

Comment: Thanks for your good idea. please give me full example of your idea to be completed answer. i want to recording video from MediaPlayer that connected ip camera with your idea, but there is many problem still. thanks in advance